# How to return result of having expression in mysql at once

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql query with subquery and aliases

```
SELECT 
k.id,
k.name AS target,
k.account_id,
k.sub_name,
k.budget,
k.cost,
k.other_bids,
k.target AS statusin,
k.rank,
k.set_rank,
(SELECT 
        COUNT(kw.id)
    FROM
        keywords AS kw
    WHERE
        kw.crc = k.crc
    GROUP BY kw.crc) AS count_kws,
(SELECT 
 SUM(IF(s.impressions, s.impressions, 0))
    FROM
        keywords AS kw
            LEFT JOIN
        stats AS s ON s.property_id = kw.property_id
            AND s.dated BETWEEN '2017-06-17' AND '2017-08-16'
    WHERE
        kw.crc = k.crc
    GROUP BY kw.crc) AS sum_impressions
 FROM keywords as k
 HAVING IF(ABS(sum_impressions),ROUND(ABS(sum_impressions) / 
 count_kws, 2),0) < 1
```

After executing query, I continue to execute the expression in having in php. How to return result of having expression in mysql  at once

Comment: If I am understanding the question, it seems you just need to add your having clause as a column (and alias it).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can't understand how to do this.

Comment: Check my Post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the query as subquery, add `HAVING` expression in `SELECT` statement and use it's alias in `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT
z.*,
IF(ABS(z.sum_impressions),ROUND(ABS(z.sum_impressions) / 
z.count_kws, 2),0) AS myexpr
FROM (
    SELECT 
    k.id,
    k.name AS target,
    k.account_id,
    k.sub_name,
    k.budget,
    k.cost,
    k.other_bids,
    k.target AS statusin,
    k.rank,
    k.set_rank,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(kw.id)
    FROM
        keywords AS kw
    WHERE
        kw.crc = k.crc
    GROUP BY kw.crc) AS count_kws,
    (SELECT 
    SUM(IF(s.impressions, s.impressions, 0))
    FROM
        keywords AS kw
        LEFT JOIN
        stats AS s ON s.property_id = kw.property_id
        AND s.dated BETWEEN '2017-06-17' AND '2017-08-16'
    WHERE
        kw.crc = k.crc
    GROUP BY kw.crc) AS sum_impressions
    FROM keywords as k
) AS z
HAVING myexpr < 1
```